# Find all coefficients of $n$ degree polynomial whose roots are $1, 2, 3, ..........n$

Tags: combinatorics, polynomials, fast-fourier-transform

Given a polynomial of degree $n$, i.e:
$$p(x) = \prod_{i=1}^n x-i=(x-1)\cdot(x-2)\cdot\ldots\cdot(x-n)$$

What will be the coefficient of each power of $x$?

I figured out the coefficient of $x^{n-k}$ is the sum of the product of all possible combinations of $k$ integers from $1$ to $n$, but I can't find a simple formula or method to compute each of these coefficients efficiently.

Can we use Inverse FFT in this case?

Comment: Note: there is no clean or simple formula.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_first_kind

Comment: Ok, so is there some faster approach/algorithm, other than naive $O(n^{2})$

Comment: You can do it with $O(n(\log n)^2)$ additions and multiplications. See https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-calculate-the-Stirling-numbers-of-the-first-kind

Comment: @Maths.Noob Please have a look [at this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28465398). I have tried to implement the algo given there, however, I have failed to get it to fit in time limits. Even a mere 10^5 degree polynomial takes ~10seconds to compute fully. While  the code given there is rescursive, mine is iterative. Please post an answer there or here (or let me know in chat and I will) if you get it to work.

Answer (score -1):

The roots of this polynomial are $\alpha_1 = 1, \alpha_2 = 2, ..., \alpha_n = n$. Let polynomial $P$ to be like this: $P(x) = x^n + a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+...+a_1x + a_0$ (it is clear that the coefficient $a_n = 1$).

By the [Vieta's formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas) we know that $\sigma_k = (-1)^k \cdot \frac{a_{n-k}}{a_n}$ (for $1 \leq k \leq n$), where $\sigma_k$ is the sum of all $k-$permutations of roots $\alpha_1,...,\alpha_n$. So, since $a_n = 1$ we get that $a_k = (-1)^{n-k}\cdot\sigma_{n-k}$ for $1\leq k \leq n -1$

I think that this is a simpler approach than Inverse FFT (if it's possible to do it that way).

Comment: Isn't the complexity of your algorithm exponential in the size of the input? ($^nC_0+^nC_1+\ldots+^nC_n=2^n$) In that case, inverse fft would fair much better.